# Error: Cannot spawn C:/Windows/system/32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe

Tags: git, git-bash

I am new to coding and I am having this problem after I think I made a booboo.  I was trying to fix an error when pushing my code to Gitlab.  After researching for means to fix the problem, I saw some tutorial that was talking about setting up GIT_SSH.  I blindly followed the steps to see if that will fix the problem, but eventually it caused a much bigger problem that the original one.

Right now, whenever I try to clone a project, I am getting this error in Gitbash:

```
error: cannot spawn C:/windows/system/32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

My assumption is, whenever I push an repo, it looks for that repo on C:/windows/system/32/openssh/ssh.exe which is non-existent (that was the link I copied from the tutorial, without thinking that I was not even on a 32 bit OS. Facepalm).  I tried typing where ssh and I get these results:

```
$ where ssh
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

This tells me that the correct path must be the first one, but Gitlab is looking for my repo on the second path.  I was hoping that someone can help me figure out how to reset this or let me change the path, and delete the C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe.

Thank you.

Comment: "/system/32"? With a slash before the 32? Isn't it just supposed to be /system32 ?